# How to disable pagination in a strapi dashboard?

Tags: strapi

I created api with strapi dashboard and it works perfectly.

Request:

*http://localhost:1337/api/tests*

Response:

```
{
“data”: [
{
“id”: 1,
“attributes”: {
“test”: “show”,
“createdAt”: “2023-10-03T12:55:11.184Z”,
“updatedAt”: “2023-10-03T13:19:44.400Z”,
“publishedAt”: “2023-10-03T12:55:39.153Z”
}
}
],
“meta”: {
“pagination”: {
“page”: 1,
“pageSize”: 0
}
}
}
```

But I want to disable pagination and not get meta values.How to do that ?

```
{
“data”: [
{
“id”: 1,
“attributes”: {
“test”: “show”,
“createdAt”: “2023-10-03T12:55:11.184Z”,
“updatedAt”: “2023-10-03T13:19:44.400Z”,
“publishedAt”: “2023-10-03T12:55:39.153Z”
}
}
]
}
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do checkout this community discussions, though its not recommended

https://forum.strapi.io/t/disabling-or-increasing-size-of-pagination/14733